# Bar-code with 22 digits number ranging from 0-9

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner

Mobile App Bar-code scanner reads printed bar-code and emits number in twenty two digits 1234567890123456789012, first twelve digits match with numbers printed on bar-code "123-456789-012", remaining ten numbers are produced even though those are not printed, what kind of bar-code it is? Do anyone know how to read, API or device which can help reading such codes?

Comment: Make sure the application itself has information on the type of barcode read. If the application does not have it, switch to an application that can obtain it, or read with a combination of barcode reader hardware, PC and another software, not a combination of mobile and application, and add information to the question.

Comment: A picture of the barcode would be helpful. Keep in mind, the number of characters that are encoded in a barcode that must be printed in human readable form near the barcode is 0.

Comment: @Brian thank you for your input, I figured out that the type of bar-code is ITF , https://www.peak-ryzex.com/articles/different-types-of-barcodes, zxing API helped to figure out the actual type.